# AWS - RDS - queries under long_query_time treshold getting saved to the slow_logs table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I configured AWS RDS parameter group with the following parameters:

```
slow_query_log: 1
long_query_time: 3.000
```

I also tried

```
long_query_time: 3.000
long_query_time: 5
long_query_time: 5000
```

but still everytime, I reboot the RDS instance, all queries are continuously logged to the slow_logs table. This is filling up the disk..

Any thoughts on how to make this work?

Comment: Have you setup any other parameters like log_queries_not_using_indexes?

Disk space should not be a problem since RDS will rotate those slow query logs automatically.
See: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_LogAccess.Concepts.MySQL.html

Comment: @SergeyKovalev you are correct, log_queries_not_using_indexes was the parameter causing the problem! After turning it off, it worked as expected.